# First character of a string fusionning with a %

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So i'm sending a String with javascript to a php page :

```
if(cp.value!=''){
    s+=cp.name +" LIKE '%"+ cp.value +"%'";
    console.log(s);

    if(sec.value!=''){
        s+=" AND "+sec.name+" LIKE '%"+ sec.value +"%'";
        console.log(s);

    }
}
else{
    if(sec.value!=''){disappear
        s+=sec.name+" LIKE '%"+ sec.value +"%'";
    }
}

console.log(s);
if(s.length!=0){
    var connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
    connect.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (connect.readyState==4 && connect.status==200){
            var resu=connect.responseText;
            console.log(resu);
            var tab=document.getElementById("main_tab");
            tab.innerHTML=resu;


        }
    };
    connect.open("POST","../../Controller/stage.php",false);
    connect.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    connect.send("s="+s);

}
```

}

The string sent is for exemple :

> CP_Stage LIKE '%90%' AND secteur_stage LIKE '%ait%'

But when i print the request in the php page i have something like :

> SELECT * FROM Stage WHERE CP_Stage LIKE '�%' AND secteur_stage LIKE '%ait%';

i have no idea why my first number disappear with the first %.
If anyone have an idea it would be awesome, thanks !

Comment: It's getting encoded.  Why not just send the  `sec.value` and build your LIKE on the other page?

Comment: Why are you constructing MySQL queries in javascript? Everyone can change the query and execute sql injections. Its not save. Don't do it this way.

Comment: Build queries on server not on client.

Comment: _“i have no idea why my first number disappear with the first %”_ - because: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: i have to make a local website so security is not problem because only one personne will have the website

Comment: What if Javascript gets disabled? You will not be able to send the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent-sign is a special charcter. Any special characters like %,&,? etc need to be encoded. Your "%90" is converted to an Ascii-Value. You have to encode these values with encodeURIComponent.

```
s += cp.name + " LIKE '" + encodeURIComponent("%" + cp.value + "%") + "'";
```

Note that encodeURIComponent does not escape the `'` character. If your cp.value has an `'` you have to replace it with its encoding value: `%27`.

By the way.. its a bad idea to send mySQL-queries from client-side - thats a major security flaw. Send only the values and build your queries on server-side.

Comment: Thank you for this solution , but yes i'll build the queries on server side.